# KMV switch, not working correctly

Tags: kvm-switch

Not sure if Superusers is the best spot to be posting this, let me know if something else is more appropriate.

I have two computers hooked up to a 4x1 USB HDMI KVM SWITCH

I use a wireless mouse and keyboard which I've plugged into one of the USB ports on the front.

When I switch from computer 1 -> 2 this happens:
- mouse and key board switch
- audio stays on computer 1
- no video on computer 2

When I go back to 2 -> 1:
- Mouse and key board switch
- audio switches to computer 2
- video works again

Anyone have any ideas on why this would happen. It was working fine. I've rebooted everything, unplugged waited and re-plugged in.

Thannks

Comment: don't know but I can tell you that I looked at reviews of kvm switches I often saw issues. sometimes a page of reviews of it might cover some solutions. I got one with top reviews. to avoid issues. the problem might be specific to that model so worth contacting the manufacturer.. That said, it's possible many kvm switches have that issue and you may get an answer here